# JSON data, HTML encoded from server or client?

Tags: json, security, underscore.js

So there's a small debate by my team, and I'm sure this is answered in many places but I couldn't find any definitive answers.

Right now we have a server that tosses up JSON data (think REST, sorta).  The client is a complete JavaScript client that uses $.ajax to grab the data and render it appropriately.

The client is using [UnderscoreJS templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to render data within the HTML:

```
<%- something %>
```

So if the server sends down a JSON block (non-html encoded):

```
{
  "username": "Joe's Crab & Cookies"
}
```

Should the server be HTML or JavaScript encoding this value?  Or should that still be left up to the client?

What if a bit of data from the server needs to be an attribute of an element:

```
<li data-item-id="<%= userId %>">something</li>
```

I realize that I shouldn't need to encode anything that's generated by the server, it's all data that is entered by the user.  So imagine the "userId" above being set by a user, not generated.

So if we encode on the server and on the client we see on the rendered page:

```
Joe's Crab &amp; Cookies
```

Comment: Please clarify `Should the server be HTML or JavaScript encoding this value?`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending json data somewhere, the only encoding that should be done to it is json encoding. You don't necessarily know if the values are going to end up in sql, javascript, xml, html attributes, a winforms app, etc.

Now, on the other hand, if some of your json values were to contain html, that html value should be encoded, ready-to-display html. It depends on context.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm not sure it's a definitive answer yet.  If someone inputs <script> tags into their input.  The server does what it needs to do to save that to the DB, but spits out "<script>" in the JSON, my co-workers get very nervous.  The "<script>" has been sent down to the client, and it's up to the client to encode the data to prevent any hack-attacks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be escaping the value, if it can be set by a user.
You should use as much escaping and validation as possible -- both on the input fields, when capturing the data on the server, when inputting into DB and, finally, when rendering it back.

Among the mild consequences of not escaping data would be that it can crack your HTML when you're outputting to `data-item-id`.

Comment: So if I escape as much as possible, I end up with the strange things rendering on the client: Joe's Crab &amp; Cookies.  This is because the server encoded the ampersand and the client then escaped what the server sent down (and printed literally &amp;)